# How to split series of text from a field then select each separately?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have a field with several strings separated by semicolon. depends on the user selection these values (length) may change. Filed Name is called Position so they have 4 choices: `teacher ; nurse; engineer; doctor`

In my db, I get this file and have to match the result from the Position field with my final report. So if any or all match with my position in my final report then display or filter my result base on these values.

So at first I need to parse or split the data in my field, then select all but select them all individually.

For example:

```
Select * from table x
      Where [position] = "teacher" ANDor " nurse" ANDor "engineer" ANDor "doctor";
```

Comment: so, 1 piece of data can have multiple positions, correct?

Comment: each field inside my Position column can have any or all of these = teacher;nurse;engineer;dcotor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, for something like this you should normalize your data:

Instead of separating by semi-colon in a text field, create a new table `position`,

```
| ID | name     |
|---------------|
| 1  | doctor   |
| 2  | engineer |
etc.
```

and another table to join the two (call it `position_xjoin`)

```
| PositionID | xID |
|------------------|
| 1          | 1   |
```

This gives you the added flexibility of being able to cope with adding new items.

Finding anyone with doctor with this structure would look like:

```
SELECT x.* FROM (x 
INNER JOIN position_xjoin ON position_xjoin.xID = x.id)
INNER JOIN position ON position_xjoin.positionID = position.id
WHERE position.name = 'doctor';
```

(where `x.id` is the pk of x)

finding anyone with doctor AND engineer would look like this:
(group by every field you want returned)

```
SELECT x.field FROM (x 
INNER JOIN position_xjoin ON position_xjoin.xID = x.id)
INNER JOIN position ON position_xjoin.positionID = position.id
WHERE position.name IN ('doctor','engineer') GROUP BY x.field
HAVING Count(x.field) = 2;
```

finding doctor OR engineer would look like this:

```
SELECT x.* FROM (x 
INNER JOIN position_xjoin ON position_xjoin.xID = x.id)
INNER JOIN position ON position_xjoin.positionID = position.id
WHERE position.name IN ('doctor','engineer')
```

Alternatively, using your structure you can 'cheat' and use `Instr()`

for doctor only:

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE Instr(Position,'doctor') > 0;
```

for doctor and engineer

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE Instr(Position,'doctor') > 0 AND Instr(Position,'engineer') > 0;
```

for doctor or engineer:

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE Instr(Position,'doctor') > 0 OR Instr(Position,'engineer') > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **IN** statement like:

```
 SELECT * from table
 WHERE [position] IN("teacher","nurse","engineer","doctor")
```

Comment: I don't need to split or parse my string?

Comment: The values of the position field has multiple values? By the way if that's the case that's a bad design.

Comment: YES one field has multi value; this file is from a sharepoint infopath form that is exported in excel so can't do anything with it and must get the data from this stupid field..

Comment: There is no `split` string function that I know of in MS Access unless you do `VBA` programming. Check this [link](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1678464-splitting-text-using-vba.html) here for the VBA thing